# Write to File in Computer running IAR Workbench

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, iar

I am currently writing and testing an embedded system in which I need to collect data from an accelerometer over a period of time.

I already have functions that can read the data at a point in time during the system's execution. At the moment, the way I was considering writing the data was through a series of printf statements; I know that IAR gives access to an I/O console where the output can be shown. What I was going to do then, was simply perform a series of printfs, ensure the data appears in the console, and after a round of testing, exit the program and copy+paste the data into a file.

This seems like kind of a hack, and I was wondering if it was possible to access the C Standard Libraries like `fwrite` to create/write a file on the computer IAR is running  and write to it. This way, I don't have to rely on `printf` statements and can then format the code as I write it to a file.

Comment: For printf you could use semihosting, SEGGER RTT, SWO, or an UART.

Comment: It should be obvious that code running on an embedded system cannot write to a development machine's filesystem at will.  Instead, you'd need something on the development machine to receive and write the data.  With a serial port this would be easy.  With debug output channeled through a debug tool, it would depend on the software running the debug tool - in your case from IAR.  See if they have support for saving log files, or writing to some sort of of pipe (though that's a weak concept in the Windows world).

Comment: According to the IAR Debugging Manual, there actually _is_ a way of running a program and having debugging information print to a file. This is done through the "C-SPY Macro" utilities of the IDE. More information is on Page 415 of the [C-SPY-Debugging Guide](http://ftp.iar.se/WWWfiles/arm/webic/doc/EWARM_DebuggingGuide.ENU.pdf)